# showing error in update in ubntu 16.04.2

Tags: updates

```
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

how do i solve it

Comment: Close voters. Not quite a duplicate. Root cause is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check indicates that Xenial isn't present there so your attempt to access anything for Xenial at that location fails: As you can see the directory structure [here](http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) has no Xenial directory whatsoever at the time of writing this answer.

[image: extras]